# Subsetting Python Datafram based on Rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some help.
I have the following dataframe (named Schedule) in Python:

[Schedule dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHKsA.png)

...And so on for 15,756 lines of courses and classes.
This data frame displays all the lectures for each course and class
E.g: Class B12 has Math on 01/12, 01/13, 01/14, 01/15, 01/16, 01/17.

What I need is a data frame that contains only the date each course starts and ends. E.g.:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jc1TU.png)

I tried to subset Schedule by the columns Class and Course:

## create a empty data frame

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i,j in Schedule[['Class', 'Course']].itertuples(index=False):

```
subset = Schedule.loc[(Schedule['Class'] == i) & (Schedule['Course'] == j)]
# extract the first row of subset:
start = subset[0,:]

# extract the Date of the last row of subset:
end = subset[subset.shape[0]-1, 0] # last row and first column of subset

# the total of lectures is equal to the number of rows of subset
total_lectures = subset.shape[0]

subset = pd.concat([start, end, total_lectures]], axis = 1)

df = df.append(subset, ignore_index = True)
```

But all I got is a series of errors that I can not interpret.

Would somebody help me please???

Comment: Try showing us what errors you have, this would help a lot. If you just tell us you have errors, we know nothing useful.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. But there are so many errors that I can not understand them! =(

Comment: Copy them, edit the question, go to the bottom, press `command+K`, paste them right into your question. This will help anyone trying to answer your question a lot.

Comment: Perhaps all you have to do is using .iloc to separate the rows that you want! Read [source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want to get the first and last date of each class, this should work for you:

```
df=Schedule.groupby('Class').agg(start=pd.NamedAgg(column='Date',aggfunc='min'),end=pd.NamedAgg(column='Date',aggfunc='max')).reset_index()
```

**Example:**

```
>>> Schedule
   Class        Date
0      3  2021-01-20
1      1  2021-01-21
2      9  2021-01-22
3      7  2021-01-23
4      1  2021-01-24
5      4  2021-01-25
6      1  2021-01-26
7      2  2021-01-27
8      1  2021-01-28
9      0  2021-01-30
0      3  2021-05-10
1      1  2021-05-11
2      9  2021-05-12
3      7  2021-05-13
4      1  2021-05-14
5      4  2021-05-15
6      1  2021-05-16
7      2  2021-05-17
8      1  2021-05-18
9      0  2021-05-20
>>> df=Schedule.groupby('Class').agg(start=pd.NamedAgg(column='Date',aggfunc='min'),end=pd.NamedAgg(column='Date',aggfunc='max')).reset_index()
>>> df
   Class       start         end
0      0  2021-01-30  2021-05-20
1      1  2021-01-21  2021-05-18
2      2  2021-01-27  2021-05-17
3      3  2021-01-20  2021-05-10
4      4  2021-01-25  2021-05-15
5      7  2021-01-23  2021-05-13
6      9  2021-01-22  2021-05-12
```

If I misunderstood the requirements, let me know